# Flutter - How to search in List and display in ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm coding a search system for the Flutter application I've developed. I'm having a problem with the back-end. First I pull the data from Firebase Firestore. Then I convert it to Model structure.

The code of the search system:

```
  StreamBuilder(
    stream: db.collection("DebrisPeoples").snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else {
        final List<DebrisPeopleModel> data = snapshot.data!.docs
            .map((e) => DebrisPeopleModel.fromDocument(e))
            .toList(); // To Model code
        return Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  final find = data.where(
                      (element) => data.contains(element.nameSurname));
                  print(find); // PROBLEM - NOT WORKING
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(
                        data[index].personSize == 1
                            ? Icons.person
                            : Icons.people,
                      ),
                      title: Text(data[index].nameSurname.toString()),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        "${data[index].city} / ${data[index].district}",
                      ),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.info),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Get.to(const UnderRublePeopleDetailPage(),
                              arguments: data[index]);
                          print(data[index].nameSurname);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    },
  ),
```

I'm having the problem in the query part. My goal is, for example, if there is a record in the form of `ABC`, I want it to appear in the results even if the user searches for `A` or `AB`.

Then I want the results to be displayed in the list. I will be grateful for your help :)

---

To change search results:

```
  final find = data.where((element) => element
      .nameSurname!
      .toLowerCase()
      .contains(value.toLowerCase()));
  print(find);
  setState(() {
    data = find.toList();
    print(data);
  });
```

I tried to make such a search system. However, the results in the `ListView` do not change as I enter the `TextFormField`.

Comment: You're applying .contains() on the wrong field.

It should be:
 ```
onChanged: (value) {
                  final find = data.where(
                      (element) => element.nameSurname.contains(value)); // You should be searching on the nameSurname on the object with value provided in the onChanged
                  print(find); // PROBLEM - NOT WORKING
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onChanged` code should be as following.

```
               onChanged: (value) {
                  final find = data.where(
                      (element) => element.nameSurname.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()));
                  print(find);
                }
```

Make sure you are managing the state to reflect the changes on UI.

**Edited**

```
final controller = TextEditingController();//Keep this as a field

  StreamBuilder(
    stream: db.collection("DebrisPeoples").snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else {
        final searchText = controller.text.trim().toLowerCase();
        final List<DebrisPeopleModel> data = snapshot.data!.docs
            .map((e) => DebrisPeopleModel.fromDocument(e))
            .where((e) => searchText.isEmpty || e.nameSurname!
            .toLowerCase().contains(searchText))
            .toList(); // To Model code
        return Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .width * 0.95,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState((){ });
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .height * 0.8,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(
                        data[index].personSize == 1
                            ? Icons.person
                            : Icons.people,
                      ),
                      title: Text(data[index].nameSurname.toString()),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        "${data[index].city} / ${data[index].district}",
                      ),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.info),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Get.to(const UnderRublePeopleDetailPage(),
                              arguments: data[index]);
                          print(data[index].nameSurname);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    },
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you help me to change `ListView` according to search? I added the code I tried by editing the topic.

Comment: Checkout my new changes